# What does さらせ do?

Tags: grammar, dialects

> **見さらせ**と言わんばかりに威風堂々と胸を張るその姿は....

What does さらせ do in this sentence? Is it a type of conjugation or is it another verb attached to 見?

Thanks!

Comment: これですね。。。http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/89580/m0u/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As choco commented, さらせ is an imperative form of さらす. It only means "do", but with bad intention and abusively.

The dictionary says its mainly used in Kansai.
見やがれ should be standard.

Comment: ”It only means "do", but with bad intention and abusively.” -- この説明、ややはしょり過ぎでは？